# How can I bulk-edit Address Book, in particular to split the contents of First Name into First Name, Last Name?

Tags: contacts

Following a MobileMe import of a Windows XP AddressBook legacy, there are hundreds of entries in the Mac Address Book like this:

```
First: Harry Potter
Last:
First: Fred Flintstone
Last:
```

It appears that what happened is that both the First and Last names in the Windows XP Address Book migrated to the Firstname field in Mac Address Book.

Is there a way to bulk-edit these?  Going through the GUI means click on first name, highlight tail, cut, click on last, paste, next.  It would be nice to do that in a text editor or with a wee perl script.

Can the Address Book be exported as structured text and subsequently replaced by modified structured text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are comfortable with AppleScript, you should be able to get it done using this web page as a starting point: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20070813135408868

Otherwise, you can export one or more cards in the vCard format, open that up in a file editor and it looks like a properly separated name field looks like this: "N:Smith;Joe;;;" so if yours look like "N:Joe Smith;;;;" and you are comfortable with regular expressions you should be able to work out a search and replace that would look for 'N:(word1) (word2);' and replace it with 'N:(word2);(word1)'. I think that would give you the right number of ';'.

Comment: And another AppleScript + ruby starting point: http://mkdynamic.wordpress.com/2007/11/10/apple-address-book-cleaner-%E2%80%93-applescript/

Answer (score 2):

You can export from inside AddressBook to vCard format which is ASCII, or use the [contacts](http://gnufoo.org/contacts/contacts.html) program to dump your AddressBook to plain text. Find the problematic entries, reformat them using your favorite scripting/programming language, or use [Google Refine](http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) if you are not a programmer, create a new CSV file, and then re-import. Check it works, then delete the originals.